# Почему тега изображения нет в скачанном HTML и как его спарсить?

Tags: c#, парсер

Пример. Вот тут, в самом нижнем посте картинка с котиком, под спойлером:

rutracker.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=381935

По идее, она должна находиться  `//img[@class="postImg"]`

Использую HtmlAgilityPack. Вывел себе посмотреть innerHTML, который загружаю - а ее там вообще нет.

Что делать?

Comment: А покажите код пожалуйста, как вы все это достаете и выполняете.

Comment: Потому что её там на самом деле нет. Она создаётся на лету джаваскриптом только после клика мышкой

Comment: Я [смотрю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/996341/213987), вы сдались и ушли с anglesharp на htmlagilitypack... А в anglesharp для подобных целей [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879818/213987) возможность подключения js: `.WithDefaultLoader().WithCss().WithJavaScript()`... Ну, что ж... разбирайтесь с каким-то одним инструментом, чтобы не погнавшись за несколькими зайцами сразу

Comment: @AK Да вот уже понял, что картинка содержится в теге <var> еще и разворачивать не надо. Но на будущее учту, что в англе можно js подключать...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Прошу прощения, вопрос решился.

Comment: @AK Извините, а не подскажете, нужно ли для каждой страницы делать            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = web.Load(url); ? Или можно web один раз создать и делать Load много раз?

Comment: Конечно можно один раз создать и делать load нужных url'ов.